# How to create a CMakeLists.txt for a gtkmm application?

Tags: c++, cmake, gtkmm

My Application tree is as follows:

```
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── example
│   ├── applicationwindow.cpp
│   ├── applicationwindow.h
│   └── Application.glade
└── main.cpp

2 directories, 5 files
```

And the `CMakeLists.txt` file I created is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)
project(Example_App)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(GTKMM gtkmm-3.0)

include_directories(${GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTKMM_LIBRARY_DIRS})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES} example/applicationwindow.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES})
```

After a successful `cmake ..` and `make` when I execute the application I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Glib::FileError'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have tried building this with a `Makefile` but that doesn't seem to give any issues. I have also tried to look into `Glib::FileError` however, I am unable to extract the exact cause of the problem. On trying the similar CMakeLists on a simpler instance like this example as denoted here: [Gtkmm Example of a Application Window](https://github.com/gammasoft71/Examples_Gtkmm/tree/master/src/Application)

It however seems to work. What might be the exact problem here?

Comment: Probably, your application fails to find the file `Application.glade`. Note, that CMake creates an executable in the build directory, which differs from the one where the source is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to be new to CMake, I will add some code around the answer provided by mohamadp91.

Your problem is that when you are running `cmake ..`, the `Application.glade` file is never copied into the `build` directory, when you run `make` and execute your software. At this point, the application tries to load a `build/example/Application.glade` file, but does not find any and you get your error.

This does not happen when using plain Makefiles because you do not build you directory in `build`, but directly alongside the `example` directory. The application can then find the Glade file.

I made a small example to reproduce your problem. It has the same directory structure:

```
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── example
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── Application.glade
└── main.cpp
```

It only has a `main.cpp` file, which tries to load a ressource (Glade file in this case, like you), under `example`. Here is the C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm.h>

constexpr int FILE_ERROR    = 1;
constexpr int MARKUP_ERROR  = 2;
constexpr int BUILDER_ERROR = 3;

Gtk::ApplicationWindow* window = nullptr;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example");
    auto builder = Gtk::Builder::create();

    try
    {
        // Try to use Application.glade:
        builder->add_from_file("example/Application.glade");
    }
    catch(const Glib::FileError& ex)
    {
      // This was your case, because the Application.glade file could
      // not be located:
      std::cout << "File error :" << ex.what() << std::endl;
      return FILE_ERROR;
    }
    catch(const Glib::MarkupError& ex)
    {
      std::cout << "Markup error :" << ex.what() << std::endl;
      return MARKUP_ERROR;
    }
    catch(const Gtk::BuilderError& ex)
    {
      std::cout << "Builder error :" << ex.what() << std::endl;
      return BUILDER_ERROR;
    }

    //Get the GtkBuilder-instantiated Dialog:
    builder->get_widget("MainWindow", window);

    if(window)
    {
        app->run(*window);
    }

    delete window;

    return 0;
}
```

The example shows how you could catch the `Glib::FileError` exception and avoid a segfault. The Glade file is simple and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkApplicationWindow" id="MainWindow">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child type="titlebar">
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkButton" id="MainButton">
        <property name="label" translatable="yes">Hello World</property>
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="receives_default">True</property>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

In the top level directory, I use the `add_subdirectory` command to tell CMake to go inside the `example` subdirectory and process the `CMakeLists.txt` file located there:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)
project(Example_App)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(GTKMM gtkmm-3.0)

include_directories(${GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTKMM_LIBRARY_DIRS})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES})

# CMake is gonna read the 'CMakeLists.txt' file located under 'example':
add_subdirectory(example)
```

In in that file, I simply copy the `Application.glade` file under `example` in the build directory:

```
file(COPY Application.glade DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to have a file named `file.glade` (this file can be anything like a `file.png`, etc.) in your program, which is located in the resource directory, you must first enter it in the program  build directory then add below code to your `CMakeList.txt`:

```
file(COPY resource DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

`resource` is your directory that contains the `file.glade` and its name can be anything you want. In your code :

```cpp
auto builder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file("resource/file.glade");
```